# Set zookeeper.connect property in Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka0.8.1. I need to set zookeeper.connect property while instantiating Producer. I am setting the property like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.put("zookeeper.connect","zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181,zookeeper1:2181/kafka");
```

But, kafka keeps on complaining this:

> [main] utils.Logging$class(83): Property zookeeper.connect is not
>   valid

I have looked here: https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html
Still, i dont understand what's wrong in "zookeeper.connect" value. I would appreciate if anyone can point out the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) page `zookeeper.connect` is a property for the `Broker` and/or the `Consumer`, not a Producer property, instead you will need to set `metadata.broker.list`, this is `section 3.3 Producer Configs`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was already setting metadata.broker.list in my code. I should have demonstrated that in my question. I was running into another problem with Kafka. I figured out the problem in my code and fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @AnilGupta and what was it?

Answer (score 0):

I just added following line:

```
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
```

Comment: where you have added consumer or producer side ?

Comment: client side I guess

Answer (score 0):

Acording to documentation, you need a semicolon-separated list of hostname. You are using a coma separated list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).